# Re-coding, can't use helper method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

What is a better (proper) way to code this according to MVC? Here's the situation:

I have a collection_select in my form, and it works fine, however I'm wanting to do something like this (note the text of the option, the 4th arg)

```
#Form.html.haml
= form_for(@payment) do |f|
 = f.collection_select(:invoice_id, Invoice.due, :id, :number + ' ' + money(:amount_due))
```

That won't work because as far as I know, you can't concat the symbols. So, I resorted to this:

```
#Form.html.haml
= form_for(@payment) do |f|
  = f.collection_select(:invoice_id, Invoice.due, :id, :number_with_amount_due)

#Invoice.rb
def number_with_amount_due
  "##{number} (#{money(amount_due)})"
end
```

Which would work if I wasn't trying to call a helper method in the Model.

So what should I do? It would be nice to be able to concat the select text in the views, but if not possible, how can I achieve what I'm trying to do while retaining proper MVC in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Largely edited my answer as I got it wrong.

Using f.select, you'll be able to provide an Array containing exactly what you need.
Assuming that Invoice.due returns your desired collection of Invoice

Here goes :

```
f.select(:invoice_id, Invoice.due.map {|i| ["#{i.number} #{money(i.amount_due)}", i.id]})
```

I think that collection_select can't achieve what you're trying to do, unless you add the helper containing `money` to your model.

Comment: That doesn't work because: `= form_for(@payment) do |f|` is the f. I'll add this to the original question. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Then if a payment `has_one :invoice` use f.object.invoice.number and f.object.invoice.amount_due

Comment: The payment `belongs_to :invoice`, not "has_one". When I tried your code (f.object.invoice.number), I get an error: `undefined method 'number' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Nice idea, I like it, and we're getting close. However, I'm getting a dropdown with `#<Invoice:0x64d356>` (similar) in both the value and text areas of each option. Which (I'm pretty sure) means it's wanting to display the object rather than call the method and display it. Any ideas why?

Comment: Yep, it's late, I used `each` instead of `map`, try with it, I edited the answer

Comment: Yup, it's late, I didn't notice it either. :) Thanks, that works perfectly. Looks like it's the simplest way!

Comment: Glad I could help :) the `select` helper has the advantage of letting you output pretty much anything in the options tags, I like it!